# JQuery Attribute Wildcards Contains space separated

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to get a element that have a attribute with a value. The attribute have multiple values. The values are space separated.

```
<div data-bind-contains="Header-Logo Footer-Logo"></div>
```

The problem with `$('[data-bind-contains*=Header-Logo]')` it will return all. That elements `$('[data-bind-contains*=Header-Logo-Something]')`, too.

```
<div data-bind-contains="Header-Logo Footer-Logo"></div>
<div data-bind-contains="Header-Logo-Looper"></div>
```

The selector `$('[data-bind-contains*=Header-Logo]')` will return both what is not my intention.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to select the element(s) where the search value is in that attribute delimited by either the beginning or end of the string and/or by spaces?

Comment: delimited on the end by spaces, like classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[~](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)** (Attribute contains word) match selector

```
$('[data-bind-contains~=Header-Logo]')
```

This will give you exact word matched within the attribute value, so this should exclude `yourword-something`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jkBW/)** to demonstrate the difference.

**[Doc](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('[data-bind-contains*="Header-Logo "]')
```

This return elements that have data-bind-contains attribute value start with **"Header-Logo "**

Put a space at the and of attribute value in jQuery so it only returns element that have value `"Header-Logo<space>+<some_other_class>"`

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you seem have no guarantee that "Header-Logo" is the first string in your list of values.

It's surely not a problem to more specifically test the value against a proper regex in the function called by the selector, is it? This may be a bit longer than needed but shows the idea....

```
$('[data-bind-contains*=Header-Logo]').click( function() {
    var str = $(this).attr('data-bind-contains');
    var pat=/\bHeader-Logo\b/;
    if (str.match( pat)) {
      // do some stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, would need to modify regex a little but it looks like PSL gave a better answer anyway